# Custom Annotation vs using @Named in JEE6

Tags: annotations, java-ee-6

Is there any difference between these two alternatives ... can they both be used interchangeably?

(A) Creating a custom annotation so @Inject can be used instead of @PersistenceContext within a DAO, as shown in the answer to - [how-to-stack-custom-annotation-in-java-with-inject-annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770465/how-to-stack-custom-annotation-in-java-with-inject-annotation/8770527#8770527)

(B) Using @Named("yourName") to qualify the Producer, such as the following code sample.

```
public class Resources {
    /**
     * EntityManager's persistence context is defined here so the @Inject annotation may be used in referencing classes.
     */
    @Produces
    @Named("MyEm")
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jboss.managed")
    private EntityManager   em;
}


@Stateless
public class FiletracksentHome {
     ..
    @Inject
    @Named("MyEm")
    private EntityManager       entityManager;
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are interchangable, but you should use (A).

The `@Named` annotation is primarily used for being able to access the object via expression language (EL), e.g. in a JSF view.

The problem is, that the resolution is done via String, thus being neither type safe, nor usually being automatically covered by refactorings in the IDE.

The [CDI specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#d0e2567) states that it should not be used for qualifying injection points if not be used to integrate legacy code.

Here's a nice [article](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#d0e2567) about this topic.